# Динамический news.xml из ленты /feed

Tags: wordpress

Как сделать динамическую выгрузку ленты /feed в файл news.xml, или чтобы по news.xml открывались данные ленты /feed ?

Comment: Спасибо за минус, но хотя бы прокомментировали в чем моя ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1. Можно добавить свой роутинг, указав WordPress, что по нему обычный фид:

```
add_action(
    'init',
    function () {
        add_rewrite_rule( 'news\.xml$', 'index.php?feed=rss', 'top' );
    }
);
```

Не забудьте сбросить реврайты, зайдя в админке в Настройки -> Постоянные ссылки.

Вариант 2. Можно добавить свой фид через `add_feed` и внутрь подсунуть стандартный фид:

```
add_action(
    'init',
    function () {
        add_feed(
            'news.xml',
            function() {
                echo file_get_contents( 'http://example.com/feed/' );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Вариант 3. Можно поправить глобальную переменную сервера, на основе которой роутинг строится:

```
add_action(
    'init',
    function () {
        if ( preg_match( '#^\/news\.xml#si', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/feed/';
        }
    }
);
```

Вариант 4. Можно подправить `query_vars`:

```
add_filter(
    'request',
    function ( $query_vars ) {
        if ( '' === $query_vars['page'] && 'news.xml' === $query_vars['pagename'] ) {
            $query_vars['feed']     = 'feed';
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/feed/';
        }

        return $query_vars;
    }
);
```

Comment: При этом условии идет редирект на /news.xml/feed/ , а мне нужно чтобы обращаясь к news.xml, я смог получить файл news.xml с статьями (все данные с index.php?feed=rss).

Comment: @tomas_morgam попробуйте второй вариант.